# Element 'referenceContainer': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( action, arguments, block, container, referenceBlock, uiComponent )

Tags: exception, magento2.3.2, developer-mode

**I am getting this error on home page**

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'referenceContainer': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( action, arguments, block, container, referenceBlock, uiComponent ).
Line: 889
```

Comment: Can you show your xml code for understand the reason behind the error

Comment: <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" layout="1column">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Satish\Addaction\Block\Test" name="helloworld" template="test.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>

Comment: it happens for layout xml files. You have to debug one by one XML .

Comment: if you remove this xml file and flush the cache then  is your issue resolve?

Comment: @AmitBera is there any way to find out from which layout file the error is coming..

Comment: I donot good to fix this issue. I debug at past  by disabled one by one module .also same pattern

Comment: Got the issue in default.xml - Thanks @AmitBera for suggestion.